# AttributeError: module 'vpython' has no attribute 'Modellearning'

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Produce learning curves for varying training set sizes and maximum depths

```
    import vpython as vs
    vs.ModelLearning(features, prices)
```

working in jupyter notebook(python 3)
please help me resolving me this error

Comment: same here. anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-project-predicting-boston-house-prices-with-regression-b4e47493633d) made by Victor Roman on "Machine Learning Project: Predicting Boston House Prices With Regression", the `vs` refers to `import visuals as vs` where the module named `visuals` is in fact the `visuals.py` script located in the same folder as the notebook.

```
# Import supplementary visualizations code visuals.py
import visuals as vs
...

vs.ModelLearning(features, prices)
```

The corresponding GitHub project (with the `visuals.py` script) can be found [here](https://github.com/rromanss23/Machine_Leaning_Engineer_Udacity_NanoDegree/tree/master/projects/boston_housing). Hope that will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of that you can use :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html